# How to return a dictionary key if its values exist in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How do I return the dictionary key if the value in a pandas DataFrame column is in the dictionary's value?

So for the `df` below how would you add a column `col3` that returns the dictionary key i.e. `odd` or `even` based on whether `col1` is in the dictionary's values?

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1,2,3,4,5], "col2": [6,7,8,9,10]})
d = {"odd": [1,3,5,7,9], "even": [2,4,6,8,10]}
df["col3"] = np.where(df["col1"].isin(d.values), d.key, "") # ???
```

I know you can use `%` or something to determine whether a value is odd or even, the above is just an example, other dictionaries might be some type of config file or json that we need to read.

Want to be able to produce something like this:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     6   odd
1     2     7  even
2     3     8   odd
3     4     9  even
4     5    10   odd
```

Comment: Remap your dictionary to `number: result` then just `df['col'].map(dictionary)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
for key in d:
   df.loc[df.col1.isin(d[key]), 'col3'] = key

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     6   odd
1     2     7  even
2     3     8   odd
3     4     9  even
4     5    10   odd
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```py
df['col3'] = df['col1'].mod(2).map({0: 'even', 1: 'odd'})
# or
d = {v:k for k, lst in d.items() for v in lst}
df['col3'] = df['col1'].map(d)
```

```
print(df)

   col1  col2  col3
0     1     6   odd
1     2     7  even
2     3     8   odd
3     4     9  even
4     5    10   odd
```

Comment: OP knows you can use mod to get odds and evens; it's an illustrative example

Comment: @ifly6 Didn't notice that, updated with another solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1,2,3,4,5], "col2": [6,7,8,9,10]})
d = {"odd": [1,3,5,7,9], "even": [2,4,6,8,10]}
data = pd.DataFrame(d).stack().reset_index()[["level_1", 0]].to_dict()['level_1']
df.col1.map(data)
```